# Java, accessing constant it future-class? (Opposite of "super")

Tags: java

```
abstract public class Item
{
    public byte getIndex()
    {
        return INDEX;
    }
}

public class Depot extends Item
{
    public static final byte INDEX = 18;
}

public class Train extends Item
{
    public static final byte INDEX = 12;
}

public class Road extends Item
{
    public static final byte INDEX = 6;
}
```

see? `Depot` has `INDEX` but `Item.getIndex()` cant reach this. Its something like opposite of "`super`", or `static::` in php.

EDIT: ok, so I can refractor this all:

```
abstract public class Item
{
    public abstract byte getIndex();
}

public class Depot extends Item
{
    public static final byte INDEX = 18;

    public byte getIndex()
    {
        return INDEX;
    }
}

public class Train extends Item
{
    public static final byte INDEX = 12;

    public byte getIndex()
    {
        return INDEX;
    }
}

public class Road extends Item
{
    public static final byte INDEX = 6;

    public byte getIndex()
    {
        return INDEX;
    }
}
```

problem: I have tons of repetitive getIndex() function.

Comment: There seems to be some code missing here...

Comment: Do you think it was supposed to access it?

Comment: no, really. Tons of items will comes from "Item", all will have an INDEX constants.

Comment: @TylerSebastian, no, no missing codes

Comment: @uoyilmaz why not? Some kind of INDEX is going to be exists, since Depot/Train/Road will have INDEX constants. In other languages, php has static:: call, to access a future-thing (virtual static thingy)

Comment: Just make `getIndex()` in `Item` abstract and have each child implement it instead of declaring a byte.

Comment: @azurefrog thats okay, but every time then I need to create an instance to access a static thing.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you; `getIndex()` isn't a static method, so you're already going to need an instance of *something* to call it.

Comment: @azurefrog, oops, yes let me clear this: this way if I want to know an index, I must do "new Depot().getIndex();" instead of "Depot.INDEX"

Comment: Now I'm sure I don't follow you... ;-)  I thought you were asking for a way to make the `getIndex()` method on the base `Item` class itself return a value based on the appropriate subclass, which is only applicable if you have an instance of something.

Comment: @azurefrog: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to see if you'd type less or more doing the things in the proper Java way.

```
abstract public class Item
{
    abstract public byte getIndex();
}

public class Depot extends Item
{
    public byte getIndex() { return 18; }
//  public static final byte INDEX = 18;
}
```

[Edited] Otherwise you'll get a nasty design pattern:

```
abstract public class Item
{
    static protected Map<Class<?>, Byte> indexes=new HashMap<Class<?>,Byte>();
    public byte getIndex() {
      return Item.indexes.get(this.getClass());
    }
}

public class Depot extends Item
{
    public static final byte INDEX = 18;
    static {
      Item.indexes.put(Depot.class, Depot.INDEX);
    }
}
```

(Just add error/exception treatment)

[Added]
**Or you can use introspection** and pay the performance penalty at runtime (+ the fact you are denying the compiler the check if the derived really declares `INDEX`)

```
abstract public class Item
{
    public byte getIndex() {
      // this will throw *at runtime* if the derived doesn't declare INDEX
      // And, as is, it's insensitive to whether or not the
      // INDEX is static or instance field (so you need to refine your
      // verifications - see the java.lang.reflect.Field)
      return this.getClass().getField("INDEX").getByte();
    }
}
```

You like the alternatives better?

Comment: @JohnSmith "problem: I have tons of repetitive getIndex() function." - well, yes. I'd suggest you the ["serenity prayer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_Prayer) especially the part with "accept the things I cannot change".

Comment: Yup.  This is the best you can get, take it or leave it, pretty much.